# A href doesnt work on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html

My web site is www.zeeb.com.tr.

I am having problem on www.zeeb.com.tr/Paketler on mobile devices.

On the page I want to click to second and third page and go to:

www.zeeb.com.tr/Paketdetay?id=1 or
www.zeeb.com.tr/Paketdetay?id=2

but instead the page isn't triggered. But clicking package isnt the same. It works most of the time but it doesn't work same like package 2 or 3.

I have tried just giving directly link with a href or jQuery window.location href option but I had the same error with both of options.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Maybe you show us some code

Answer (score 0):

I was using onmouseover event for package divs in jquery to be widened and it was being trigered on mobile devices. To prevent this I changed package divs' ids with different id names on mobile and tablet media queries so that onmouseover event is not triggered.